# Resize in lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, responsive-design

I have a problem and need help .

With this code, I'm trying to have a responsive display and also I want that my composent not to be impacted with zoom that's why I used "addEventListener" but when for exemple the zoom is 100% it is good , when It is 75% or less than 100% no .

```
 connectedCallback(){
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.myFunction);
    }

    @track count = 0;
    myFunction = () => {
        this.count = this.count += 1;
        console.log('resized => ', this.count);
    };
```

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-page-header">
            <div class="slds-page-header__row">

                <template if:true={MyObj.data}>
                            
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">

                            <div class="slds-col ">
                                <span>
                                    <span class="slds-m-around_medium style">
                                        <img style="     width: 40%;
                                          margin-top: 12%; " src={icon}   >
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                                </div>

                            <div class="slds-col">
                                
                                <div><br>
                                    <div class="position1">
                                    <div>
                                        <h1><strong>{Name}</strong></h1>
                                    </div><br><br></div>
                                    <div class="position1">
                                    <div>
                                        <h1><strong>{Formula__c}</strong></h1>
                                    </div><br><br></div>
                                    <div class="titlePosition2">
                                    <div>
                                      <h1><strong>{Type__c}</strong></h1>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                            </div>
                            </div>
        
                           

                                <div if:true={imageborder}>
                                    <div class="slds-col"> 
                                        <span>
                                             <lightning-spinner if:true={isLoading} alternative-text="Loading" size="small"> 

                                             </lightning-spinner> 
                                             <div style="max-width:95% ;">
                                                  <img style="max-width:85%;max-height:90%; height: 220px; width: 480px; " src ={imageurl} >
                                                 </div>
                                                 </span>
                                                 </div>
                                                </div>

                                               
                                                
                            <div class="slds-col">
                                <span>
                            <div style="margin-top: 85%; margin-left: -35%;" >
                                <lightning-file-upload  name="fileUploader"  accept={acceptedFormats} record-id={recordId} onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished} onchange={saveFile} disabled={disableImport}>
                                </lightning-file-upload>
                            </div>
                                <div>
                                    <template if:true={fileName}>
                                            {fileName} &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                                    </template>
                                </div>
                            
                                </span>
                        </div>
                            <div class="slds-col">
                            <span> 
                                <lightning-map style="width: 90%;"
                                map-markers={mapMarkers}
                                zoom-level={zoomLevel}
                                center={center}
                                onmarkerselect={handleMarkerSelect}
                                selected-marker-value={selectedMarkerValue}
                            >
                            </lightning-map>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                          
                            
                            <div class="slds-col">
                            <span>
                                <div class="StyleAdress">
                                    <p >{Country}</p><br>
                                    <p>{City}</p><br>
                                    <p>{Street}</p>
                                </div>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                            </div>



                </template>
        </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: I would recommend reading about [Responsive Page Design](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_responsive.htm) using SLDS. Why would you want to _not_ allow the user to zoom in? What if they have a hard time seeing and need to enlarge screen content?

Comment: @nbrown  I don't want to prevent the zoom, but I want my component to take into account the zoom, if it's 100% take all the space if it's less also take all the space and not that it decreases and all the other parts their places change

Comment: Make sure your [grid](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/) is set up the way you need it to be. It's hard to say what's not responsive about your layout without copying and running your code. `slds-grid slds-wrap` could go a long way.